# Can't connect to HSQL Database from Java code when HSQL Database Manager is Connected

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

When I have opened and connected HSQL DB Manager (Swing), Java code can't connect to database throwing this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@cf53680[file =C:\somedb\db.lck ...
```

But as soon as I close the connection to database from Database Manager, Java code starts to work fine.

What is this?

Comment: delete the .lck file first and run the prog

Comment: Using SQLite database? If so you can not have concurrent connections, use a production ready database instead such as MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc,,,

Comment: @Satya Just deleting the lock is not an option. the HSQL connection needs to lock the database to prevent any other access. The lock file will go when the database connection is closed and then other clients can connect. Using a production ready database is the solution

Comment: Dear Satya, I've read that in Google.. but that doesn't help :(

Comment: thanks for the knowledge sharing @jamesc

Comment: @Jamesc no, as I have mentioned I use HSQL database.. but what you mean can't have concurrent connection? :) so If I want to have my program connected to db and want to have a look on database tables - that's impossible? :))

Comment: Yes, That's impossible. Concurrent = multiple connections at the same time. Usually a lock is only generated when a table is opened for write access, Paradox used to do this. Use a full production database rather than HSQL is the best option, one that will scale well as previously suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HSQLDB is primarily an *embedded* database engine. That means that if you run it embedded, only one process (=JVM) can use the database. Connections from other processes are not possible.

The only way around that is to start HSQLDB in **server** mode where HSQLDB runs in its own process (JVM) and accepts connections from other processes - essentially the same setup as a "traditional" database server like Postgres or Oracle.

Details on how to start HSQLD in server mode are documented in the manual:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes

Comment: @Giorgi Tsiklauri, I would suggest this is your work around solution